# Como trabalhar com DataGridViewCheckBox usando uma chekBox aparte que permite habilitar e desabilitar todos os campos da DataGridView?

Tags: c#

Estou a ter algumas dificuldades em trabalhar com *DataGridViewCheckBox* usando uma *chekBox* aparte, quase tudo esta a funcionar na normalidade,o problema esta ao usar a opção selecionar tudo, que é a *chekBox* que adicionei a parte, por exemplo: quando seleciono duas linhas e de pois clico no selecionar tudo, acontece que ele desabilita as duas linhas selecionada e habilita as demais linhas que não estavam selecionadas.

Eis ai o código:

```
private void chk_Selecionar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Entrada.Rows)
{
 DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
 chk.Value = !(chk.Value == null ? false : (bool)chk.Value); 
}
```

Como faço, para que quando eu clicar em selecionar tudo ele habilita todos os campo e se por acaso tiver já um campo habilitado ele mantem habilitado, e quando desabilitar a opção selecionar tudo, ele desabilita todos os campos?

Comment: 'chk.Value = true;' irá deixar todos os campos habilitados. Este código é usado para desabilitar também?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterei seu código para levar em consideração o valor do seu checkbox que faz o papel de "selecionar tudo". É para funcionar corretamente agora;

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Entrada.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
   chk.Value = (chk.Value == null ? false : chk_Selecionar.Checked); // O nome do seu checkbox selecionar tudo acessando a propriedade "Checked"
}
```

Comment: ok, agora sim funcionou valeu meu